# VB.NET: Fields from a class

Tags: vb.net, class, file

I have a class being populated from comma separated rows in a text file.

I am trying to have the name property of each object appear in a listbox, then have the rest of the properties of a selected object show up in text boxes. How do I load the properties of the selected object to the correct textbox?

Comment: What is the type of each object? How are the text file contents being mapped onto this type of object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the class you fill has a list of the objects and that you have already figured out how to fill the listbox...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    For Each obj As YourObjectType In YourClass.CollectionOfYourObjects

        If obj.Name = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString Then

            Textbox1.Text = obj.Property1
            Textbox2.Text = obj.Property2

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one TextBox for every Property and the number of properties is static, isn't it?
You have to set the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) to the Property's name that you want to see in the Listbox.

This simplified sample should work:

```
Public Class ListBox
    Private Sub ListBox_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim allFoos As New List(Of FooClass)
        For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
            Dim foo As New FooClass
            foo.Name = "Foo_" & i
            foo.Prop1 = "Prop1_" & i
            foo.Prop2 = "Prop2_" & i
            foo.Prop3 = "Prop3_" & i
            allFoos.Add(foo)
        Next
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = allFoos
        Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim foo As FooClass = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, FooClass)
        Me.TxtName.Text = foo.Name
        Me.TxtProp1.Text = foo.Prop1.ToString
        Me.TxtProp2.Text = foo.Prop2.ToString
        Me.TxtProp3.Text = foo.Prop3.ToString
    End Sub
End Class

Class FooClass
    Private _name As String
    Private _prop1 As Object
    Private _prop2 As Object
    Private _prop3 As Object

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Prop1() As Object
        Get
            Return _prop1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            _prop1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Prop2() As Object
        Get
            Return _prop2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            _prop2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Prop3() As Object
        Get
            Return _prop3
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            _prop3 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```